# Calculating volume of sphere in Water Tower Calculator Program - Java

Tags: java

For this problem I need to write a program that prompts and asks the user for the width of the sphere in inches and then calculates the area in inches, area in feet, volume in inches, volume in feet, and gallons of water.Pi and the gallons conversion variable (7.48) are constants. The equations used to get these calculations are:

```
A = 4*pi*r^2
AFt = A / 12
V = 4/3 * pi * r^3
VFt = V / 1728
Gallons of water = VFt * 7.48
The test width value is 400. This should give me the output of 
A = 502,400.00
AFt = 41,866.67
V = 33,493,333.33
VFt = 2,791,111.11
Gallons of Water = 20,877,511.11
```

Here is my code so far. The first two calculations are correct but I am having trouble correctly calculating the Volume, volume in feet, and gallons of water. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class WaterTowerCalculator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the width of the sphere");
            int width = scan.nextInt();

            final double PI = 3.14;
            final double C_VARIABLE = 7.48; 
            double w = width; 
            double r = w/2;
            double A = 4*PI*r*r;
            double AFt = (double) A/12;
            double V = (4/3)*PI*(r*r*r);
            double VFt = (double) V/1728;
            double gallons = (double) VFt * C_VARIABLE; 

            System.out.printf("Area in inches " +"%,.2f\n", A);
            System.out.printf("Area in feet " + "%,.2f\n", AFt);
            System.out.printf("Volume in inches " + "%,.2f\n", V);
            System.out.printf("Volume in feet " + "%,.2f\n", VFt);
            System.out.printf("Gallons of water " + "%,.2f\n", gallons);                

        }

    }
```

Comment: Saying *I'm having trouble* is totally useless as a problem description unless you explain specifically what *trouble* you're having. What **specific** question can we help you with?

Comment: You should make `width` should be `double` and accept it with `nextDouble()`.  Otherwise, the calculation of `r` is done in integer arithmetic and won't give the  right result if `width` is odd.   That aside, spheres don't always come in nice convenient integral numbers of inches wide; why, it was just the other day I needed to find the gallon capacity of a sphere exactly 214.4358349 inches in diameter...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using integer division when you want floating point division.

Replace e.g. `4/3` with `4.0 / 3.0`.

Comment: lol of course just a simple fix like this was the answer, thank you!

Comment: if you found the answer helpful, consider accepting it? :-)